# Managing intents in google dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am New to the Google dialogflow.
I created the Agent and intents.
Now i gave some user utterances (Training Phase) in intent. When user input related to the training phase response is coming.
User input other than the utterances it is going to fallback intent.
But i need user input does not matches to the utterances dialogflow must give the appropriate response as user need.
how to solve the situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to make more intents for that, anything which is not matching any intent will go to default fallback intent

Comment: Can you give an example (possibly by posting a screen shot, or just showing the conversation) of what you're expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: For Example: intent1 expected answer is "job" if user gives another words it will go the fallback intent.But i need if user gives any other words the flow must continue to intent2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two options for your situation:

1. Create more intents and train them to improve your agent's accuracy for the intents. This is what you are supposed to do if you have a lot of training data. If not, try the option 2.
2. Create a custom Fallback Intent with an input/output context.

Option 1. is obvious like [sid8491](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3196845/sid8491) is saying.
Option 2. is kind of a hack, but I think it can solve your situation by providing the correct input context and solved mine too.

One example is when you want to ask users to write feedback. Since users can write any feedback (i.e. it's hard to train the feedback intent with data beforehand), this is where a custom fallback intent comes in. Since you expect feedback from your user, you set an input context for your custom feedback fallback intent and users response (feedback) will match your feedback intent.

You can create a custom Fallback Intent by clicking the three dots right next to "CREATE INTENT" in Intent tab.

Hope it helps.